# What is geometric engine of inkscape?

Tags: c++, geometry, inkscape

I like possibility to edit paths in Inkscape via boolean operations on shapes, offseting etc. I want to investigate background algorithms, because they look very reliable and fast. What is the geometric library, used by Inkscape?

Answer (score 1):

The geometric engine used by Inkscape is (*drumroll*): **Inkscape**. Inkscape has its very own geometry engine and does not rely on 3rd party code for that part.

In fact Inkscape has a headless mode where you can control it via commands on stdin and quite a number of open source vector graphics tools make use of it.

Comment: What about 2geom library? I thought that it implemented geometry algorithms

Comment: @АлександрЛысенко: Essentially 2geom is an extraction of the geometry engine of Inkscape into an independent library. It's however not used by Inkscape. There's a dedicated page in the Inkscape development wiki tracking external dependencies: http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Tracking_Dependencies – only the 3rd party code mentioned there is what Inkscape does not contain itself. It should be noted that in growing software projects is quite usual to compartement the application code into modules (aka libraries) that are fully contained within the final application.

Comment: @АлександрЛысенко: For example in most of my own programs that grow beyond "quick and dirty hack" each major functionality (GUI, business logic, data management) is developed as self contained library; on quite often these libraries split out into several sublibraries. geom2 is merely a standalone version of some submodule of Inkscape.

Comment: So, As far as I understand, I should search needed algorithms, spreaded across entire Inkscape project in different libraries?

Comment: @АлександрЛысенко: It's a fair assumtion that everything related to geometrical processing will be organized closely together. After all that's what libraries are about: Packing up conceptionally similar things.